# Every perfect set is not discrete??

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, cantor-set

Let X be a set with discrete topology. So, every singletons are open. This means every point in X can not be a limit point of X. If X is perfect, every point must be limit point, but it is not. Thus, perfect set can’t be discrete.

I wanted to show that Cantor set is not discrete, and therefore infinite product of {0,1} with discrete topology is not discrete since it is homeomorphic to Cantor set.

Am I right??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. Personally, I think that proving that the Cantor set is not discrete directly from the definition (of the Cantor set) is more natural, but it's a matter of taste.

Comment: Thank you! So, is it better to show there is a point in Cantor set which is not open?

Comment: @ylh0501 Please don't say “better”; it's just a matter of taste. But if your goal is just to prove that the Cantor set is not discrete, that that's how I would do it, yes. It's enough to use the fact that$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac2{3^n}=0.$$

Comment: I see. My bad. And wow. It’s so simple. Thank you so much!